# How to 'apply' soft symbolic links

Tags: shell, files, symlink

Is there a command to 'apply' a soft symlink?
As in delete the symlink and make a copy of where the symlink pointed to and put it where the old symlink was.

I could make a program or alias to do that, but it seems like there would be a build-in command for that.

Comment: Hi ! Does this answer your question ? https://superuser.com/questions/303559/replace-symbolic-links-with-files
Especially the answer with `cp -L` ?

Comment: @alex_reader `cp -L` can’t do this in one go, it refuses to copy files over themselves (so `cp -L symlink symlink` doesn’t work).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don’t think there’s a “standard” command to do that (referring only to the symlink), but it doesn’t take much:

```
(rm symlink && cat > symlink) < symlink
```

will replace `symlink` with a file with the contents of the file it pointed to.

Comment: This works great for files but for directories I need something a tad longer: `cp -r \`readlink -f symlink && rm symlink\` symlink`